# iOS identify user(s)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am building app that will serve some content to the users via my private server. At the server-side I would like to identify user, so that I don't serve same content twice to the same user. How can I identify user(s)?

One way is DeviceID, but user can have multiple devices...?

Is the only way to have my own user IDs for my application (registration). I don't like this as it adds extra complexity to the app.

Comment: One user have more than 1 device also may be more than 1 user use same device some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's a hard task, but maybe facial recognition (from the webcam) could help in logging in users, since it doesn't imply any relation between user and device.
For example, [face.com](http://developers.face.com/docs/) offers a free web-based API for facial recognition.

Although, [Ishu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/483888/ishu)'s answer (username/password) is the easiest and most standard way to do identify users.

Answer (score 1):

Make an id for user's and also a login page in the app. save his id with in you content table for send that content for that user. if that content entry already having his id then don't send to him otherwise send to him.

I don't think there is another option. You must use user id nothing else.

Comment: Yes I know I can do that but as noted in my original post I would like to avoid login/registration part in my app. Adds unnecessary complexion to the app. If there is no other way I will use DeviceID and will only tie stuff to this information.

Comment: Then i think you need to use device id. because you can't do it without identifying either user or device so in case of user identification you need to register user.